# Label e Legenda no gráfico ChartJs Doughnut Charts

Tags: chartjs

Alguém saberia como incluir Legenda e Label acima do gráfico neste tipo abaixo?
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

Criei o meu, mas já inseri todas as options da documentação e o label só aparece quando passo o mouse em cima.

Comment: A sintaxe é: `myChart.generateLegend();`

Answer (score 0):

Com uma instância de Chart qualquer, apenas invoque o método `.generateLegend()`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
<div id="legenda"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
];

var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart").getContext("2d");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
// Legenda
document.getElementById('legenda').innerHTML = myPieChart.generateLegend();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Muito provavelmente você também vai querer alterar o HTML/template da legenda, então você deve passar, via `options` para o chart a propriedade `legendTemplate` com o respectivo template.

Comment: A legenda até não seria tanto o problema, mas o que preciso é que fique o label acima do gráfico. Será que tem como?

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o método '.generateLegend()' para gerar a legenda.
Esse método retorna uma string HTML com a legenda de acordo com o modelo passado na opção do gráfico 'legendTemplate'.